# Seasonal linear regression in R: p-value

Tags: r, regression, seasonality

I'm trying to understand how to plug seasonality into a linear regression.

I started with this simple code

```
model <- lm(airquality,formula = Ozone ~ Solar.R + factor(Month))

summary(model)
```

Where I got these results

```
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      3.2189     7.9190   0.406 0.685220    
Solar.R          0.1148     0.0300   3.828 0.000220 ***
factor(Month)6   5.0690    10.9801   0.462 0.645284    
factor(Month)7  31.0419     8.0184   3.871 0.000188 ***
factor(Month)8  36.9034     8.2013   4.500 1.76e-05 ***
factor(Month)9   8.9121     7.7629   1.148 0.253563    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 28.09 on 105 degrees of freedom
  (42 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.3197,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2873 
F-statistic: 9.871 on 5 and 105 DF,  p-value: 9.336e-08
```

My question is, I applied a factor to understand the impact of each month, but for Month 6 and 9 I get p-values much larger than 0.05, meaning that I cannot reject the null hypothesis of those values being 0.
What is the meaning of these results? Can I conclude that those 2 months doesn't have any impact on the Ozone variable?

Also, how the formula would look like? (I assume the intercept is 0, due to p-value > 0.05).

```
Month 7

y = 0.1148 * x + 31.0419 * 7
```

```
Month 8

y = 0.1148 * x + 36.9034 * 8
```

Comment: Recall that when using factor one category is estimated by the intercept. Therefore, generally, the indicators tell you whether those categories are different from the reference category (month 5, in your case, which is not statistically different from zero). In other words, those are binary indicators, therefore there is no need to multiply them by their value. You can verify this by creating dummy variables and using them in the regression, instead of using factor.

Comment: Okay, but what does it mean that the p-value > 0.05? I understand that if that happens with an "x" variable such as Solar.R or Wind I can exclude them from the model, to have a better fit, but I'm confused what happens with Month as a factor. In other words, I want to see what's the impact of Time/Month without excluding them from LM formula.